# Swipe in listview of contact

Tags: android, listview

Hy all,

In my APP in need show list of contact (it's ok for the moment) in the listview.

And I want when in swipe in the right of the number the APP call the number.

I have this for the moment :

MainActivity :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, new FragContact()).commit();
```

In my frag :

```
public class FragContact extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == true) {
                    explain();
                } else {
                    //demander l'autorisation
                }
            } else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

                final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                final List<Map<String, Object>> contacts = retrieveContacts(getActivity().getContentResolver());
                if (contacts != null) {
                    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), contacts, R.layout.contact, new String[]{"contactNumber", "photo"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                            R.id.photo});
                    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
                            if ((view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap)) {
                                final ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
                                final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data;
                                image.setImageBitmap(photo);
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                return rootView;
            }

            return null;
        } else {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            final List<Map<String, Object>> contacts = retrieveContacts(getActivity().getContentResolver());
            if (contacts != null) {
                final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), contacts, R.layout.contact, new String[]{"contactNumber", "photo"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                        R.id.photo});
                adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
                        if ((view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap)) {
                            final ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
                            final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data;
                            image.setImageBitmap(photo);
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public List<Map<String, Object>> retrieveContacts(ContentResolver contentResolver)
    {
        final List<Map<String, Object>> contacts = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null)
        {
            Log.e("retrieveContacts", "Cannot retrieve the contacts");
            return null;
        }

        if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
        {
            do {
                final long id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
                final String contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                if (contactNumber != null) {
                    final Bitmap photo = getPhoto(contentResolver, id);
                    final Map<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    contact.put("contactNumber", contactNumber);
                    contact.put("photo", photo);
                    contacts.add(contact);
                }
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext() == true);
        }

        if (cursor.isClosed() == false)
        {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contacts;
    }
    private Bitmap getPhoto(ContentResolver contentResolver, long contactId)
    {
        Bitmap photo = null;
        final Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        final Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(photoUri, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DATA15 }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null)
        {
            Log.e("getPhoto", "Cannot retrieve the photo of the contact with id '" + contactId + "'");
            return null;
        }

        if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
        {
            final byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);

            if (data != null)
            {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            }
        }

        if (cursor.isClosed() == false)
        {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return photo;
    }

    private void askForPermission()
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS }, 2);
    }

    private void explain()
    {
        askForPermission();

    }
}
```

Actualy I have there :

[image]

Thank for you're help.

Comment: Something like swipe to dismiss (labeled **Leave-behinds** in the [design documentation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists-controls.html#)), but calling a number instead?

Comment: Hum where you swipe left to right you called the number instead and where you swipe to right to left you have icon to sms.